# Visual Studio does not recognize BindingInflate function of MvxFragment

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have the following class:

```
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Fragging;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Fragging.Fragments;

public class DifficultyItemFragment : MvxFragment
{
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        return this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.DifficultyItemFragment, null);
    }
}
```

and I get the following error:

```
 Error  8   ...'QuickShift.Android.Views.DifficultyItemFragment' does not contain a definition for 'BindingInflate' and no extension method 'BindingInflate' accepting a first argument of type 'QuickShift.Android.Views.DifficultyItemFragment' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I looked at the MvvmCross source code and BindingInflate does indeed exist within the BindingContext namespace.

Am I missing something?? I have all the necessary libraries referenced, including Xamarin.Android.Support.v4

[image]

**UPDATE:**

I've created a sample project in VS 2013 to illustrate the problem. You'll notice that in Fragment1.cs the same problem exists:

[Sample app](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=DCC93DD825EF3F43!7915)

Comment: What version of MvvmCross are you using? I just loaded Stuart's N+1 N=26 and updated to current 3.1.1 and everything looks good. Are you able to build the sample? If not, you may want to compare the versions and project settings.

Comment: I also have 3.1.1, I don't understand why it wouldn't see function, I have a feeling it might have something to do with one of the references, I'll attach a screenshot.

Comment: Hmm.. aside from your project specific references, it looks the same here. What are your Android project settings? Were you able to get the sample working?

Comment: I've updated my OP with a link to a sample project with the same problem.

Comment: I wasn't able to build it either until I added the following: using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.BindingContext;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`BindingInflate` is actually an extension method. You need to import the correct namespace (for version 3.5.x).

```
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.BindingContext;
```

For version 4.x, MvvmCross has reorganized the namespaces. The correct import is:

```
using MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.BindingContext;
```

**EDIT: Added version info to answer and included updated namespace for v4.x**

Comment: That's it!!  I was using using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext; instead and I didn't know about the Droid namespace.

Thank you!

Comment: An addition to that. If you update to the MVVMCross then the reference changes to: using MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.BindingContext;

Comment: Yes, I need to start putting version numbers on my answers... "As of version X.Y.Z". Software changes so fast that it's hard to keep up.